# Evolution mail client: does it have "copy sent to current" like TB's plugin

Tags: evolution

The "Copy Sent To Current" plugin for Thunderbird allows me to select a folder to store an outgoing mail into while composing the email. The email being answered is filed into that folder too.

I know that something similar can probably be maintained with filter rules, but just choosing the folder while creating the email is extremely convenient. Is there something like this for Evolution?